# Dynamic Table Rows using XSLT and XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT and XML. I'm trying to make a dynamic list based on how many CASES come back from an XML file.

The XML section about CASES looks like this:

```
...
<CASES>
    <CASE>000000000000014-00001</CASE>
    <CASE>000000000000014-00002</CASE>
    <CASE>000000000000014-00003</CASE>
</CASES>
...
```

My XSLT code (excerpt) for the table I'm creating looks like this:

```
...
CASES:
<table style="width: 100%;">
<xsl:for-each select="CASES/CASE">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="CASE"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
...
```

The output is three blank table rows. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `xsl:for-each` loop alread selects `CASE` elements,

```
<xsl:for-each select="CASES/CASE">
```

your `xsl:value-of` shouldn't be

```
    <td><xsl:value-of select="CASE"/></td>
```

because that looks for a `CASE` child of the current `CASE` element.

Instead, within the loop just select the current element itself, available as `.`:

```
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. It put them side by side. Any advice on how I can get them each in their own row?

Comment: Your shown XSLT snippet already has them in their own row by virtue of the `<tr>...</tr>` that wraps the single `td` elements within the `CASE` loop.